# Transforming for loops into a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, finance

My code is attempting to create a list of cashflow values over the life of a loan (including a default scenario). If I run the code as-is, I get exactly the answers that I need. However, after e-mailing the code to my professor, he told me that it needed to be in functions. I'm not very good at functions. Any ideas?

```
cashflows_before_default = 0

cashflows_before_default_list = []

for i in range(0, default_year[0]): 
    cashflows_before_default = cash_flows[i]
    cashflows_before_default_list.append(cashflows_before_default)

cashflows_after_default = 0

cashflows_after_default_list = []

for i in range(default_year[0], default_year[0]+2):
    cashflows_after_default = 0
    cashflows_after_default_list.append(cashflows_after_default)

for i in range(default_year[0]+1, (default_year[0]+2)):
    cashflows_after_default = model_data.price_machine * model_data.recovery_rate
    cashflows_after_default_list.append(cashflows_after_default)

total_loan_cashflows = cashflows_before_default_list + cashflows_after_default_list
total_loan_cashflows
```

Comment: Please be more specific, see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Look, each loop can be seen as a function, good functions usually doesn't have any argument.

Example:

```
def loop1(default_year):
  cashflows_before_default = 0
  cashflows_before_default_list = []
  for i in range(0, default_year[0]): 
    cashflows_before_default = cash_flows[i]
    cashflows_before_default_list.append(cashflows_before_default)

  return cashflows_before_default,cashflows_before_default_list
```

what's the point ?? you may ask and the answer is make the code more readable
instead of reading a bunch of loops if you do it right you will read just a cooke receipt like:

```
doFunction1()
doFUnction2()
doFunction3()
```